# adding custom JSON payloads for TELEGRAM in Dialogflow to get users to share their phone number

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

the function below  is supposed to provides the fulfillment to the share_your_phone_number intent.
When the intent is invoked, the share your phone number keyboard is displayed for the user in telegram.

```
function share_your_phone_number(agent) {
agent.add(`Welcome.`);
agent.add(new Payload("telegram", {
    "text": "Please click on button below to share your number",
    "reply_markup": {
      "one_time_keyboard": true,
      "resize_keyboard": true,
      "keyboard": [
        [
          {
            "text": "Share my phone number",
            "callback_data": "phone",
            "request_contact": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "text": "Cancel",
            "callback_data": "Cancel"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
 ));
}
```

When I deploy the API in the inline editor, only the "Welcome" string is returned in telegram bot chat. the key board buttons are not displayed.

I need a clue to fix fix this.

Answer (score 3):

In creatin the Constructor for Payload object as documented [here]https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/rich-responses#new_payloadplatform_payload, the `platform` and `payload` parameters are required.

`new Payload(platform, payload)`

The `platform` parameter is a property of WebhookClient object and should be defined as such (agent.SLACK, agent.TELEGRAM etc) assuming the webhookClient was instantiated and stored in `agent`

**Examples:**

`agent.add(new Payload(agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE, {/*your Google payload here*/});`
`agent.add(new Payload(agent.SLACK, {/*your Slack payload here*/});`

`agent.add(new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, {/*your telegram payload here*/});`

ref: https://blog.dialogflow.com/post/fulfillment-library-beta/.

For my use-case outlined in the question this is my full solution:

```
    // See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
    // for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
    'use strict';

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Text, Card, Image, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'); 
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    function welcome(agent) {
      agent.add(new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, {

        "text": "Please click on button below to share your number",
        "reply_markup": {
          "one_time_keyboard": true,
          "resize_keyboard": true,
          "keyboard": [
            [
              {
                "text": "Share my phone number",
                "callback_data": "phone",
                "request_contact": true
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "text": "Cancel",
                "callback_data": "Cancel"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
       }));
      }

      // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

Comment: Hm, I just tried it with Slack. It doesn't show up :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my result:

```
  function welcome(agent) {
    const payload = {
      "text": "Pick a color",
      "reply_markup": {
        "inline_keyboard": [
          [
            {
              "text": "Yellow",
              "callback_data": "Yellow"
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              "text": "Blue",
              "callback_data": "Blue"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    };

    console.log('queryText ' + JSON.stringify(agent.request_.body.queryResult.queryText));
    console.log('displayName ' + JSON.stringify(agent.request_.body.queryResult.intent.displayName)

    agent.add(
      new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, payload, {rawPayload: false, sendAsMessage: true})
    );
  }
```

Also you must update version of `dialogflow-fulfillment` in package.json to latest. Now I have this version - `"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1"`